# How to find semantic similarity between a list of words?

Tags: python, spacy, semantics, similarity

Input:

```
listToStr = 'degeneration agents alpha alternative amd analysis angiogenesis anti anti vegf appears associated based best bevacizumab blindness blood'
```

Code I am using:

```
simi = []
tokens = nlp(listToStr) 
length = len(tokens)

for i in range(length):
    #print(i)
    sim = tokens[i].similarity(tokens[i+1])
    simi.append(sim)
print(simi)
```

Error:

```
[E040] Attempt to access token at 17, max length 17.
```

How can I remove this error?

I am using spacy. Here's the link to it:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-word-similarity-using-spacy/#:~:text=Python%20%7C%20Word%20Similarity%20using%20spaCy,simple%20method%20for%20this%20task.

Comment: You're using some kind of nlp library - it's not clear which one, or how it works - and the error looks as though it belongs to that library. It would be helpful if you state what that library is, and perhaps link to a document page for it.

Comment: please check, added the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop, an index that is out of range for the list of tokens is created as a consequence of the `tokens[i + 1]` operation. You could do something like this instead:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

listToStr = 'degeneration agents alpha alternative amd analysis angiogenesis anti anti vegf appears associated based best bevacizumab blindness blood'

simi = []
tokens = nlp(listToStr) 

for idx, tok in enumerate(tokens):
    sim = []
    for nextok in tokens[idx:]:
        sim.append(tok.similarity(nextok))
    simi.append(sim)
```

This test the similarity of each word with the next words in the sentence, so the result is a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can I also also get the pair of word in the list, for which it has calculated the similarity?

Comment: No problem :) You can achieve this last thing with `sim.append([tok, nextok, tok.similarity(nextok)])` if you don't mind having it in the same list.